# Unable to change color of object in SVG from an SVG def

Tags: css, html, svg

I would like to change the color of an SVG element when using it.
But I can't figure out how to make it work.
It works however when I don't use the SVG as a definition but just as inline SVG.

The following block of SVG definitions is at the top of page:

```
<svg style="display:none;">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 410 410" id="diamond"><title>diamond</title>
    <rect x="63.579" y="62.383" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -84.0685 204.6499)" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="282.843" height="282.843"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

When using it I use it as follows:

```
<div class="diamonds">
<svg>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#diamond"></use>
</svg>
</div>
```

My CSS code to change the color of the rect is the following:

```
.diamonds {
    svg {
      rect {
        stroke: green;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: rect is not within svg, rect is inside symbol, which is inside svg.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "see inside" a `<use>` element with CSS.  The things it is referencing don't become children of it as far as the DOM and CSS are concerned.  However if you apply the style you want to the `<use>` element, it will be inherited by elements in the symbol.

```css
.diamonds svg use {
    stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none;">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 410 410" id="diamond"><title>diamond</title>
    <rect x="63.579" y="62.383" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -84.0685 204.6499)" stroke-width="15" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="282.843" height="282.843"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>


<div class="diamonds">
<svg>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#diamond"></use>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just give the `use` a class and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to also use:

```
svg rect {
 fill: inherit;
}
```

Have a look at this post and the section
"Overriding Presentation Attribute Values From CSS"
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/